# Odoo 9 - cannot load custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am brand new to odoo, just installed version 9 and made a module 'aidentest' using

.>>python odoo.py scaffold aidentest addons

That created the aidentest module in the addons folder. Uncommented everything in the autogenerated files

but when I went to check out my 'Hello World' page at

http://localhost:8069/aidentest/aidentest

I got a 404 not found

So I went to apps to try and load my module, but I could not find it.

Does anyone know what I need to do on Odoo 9 to load up and start coding my custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly: **You have to activate developer mode by going to Top right menu>about>activate developer mode**

---

I had basically given up, and was mindlessly clicking about when I hit the 'About' link on the generic-whiteguy dropdown. *I had to actually stop thinking before I was able to locate the completely senseless place where they put the thing I need.*

The About modal window popped up, and in it was an **activate the developer mode** button

Some things changed immediately, but I still couldn't find my custom module.

Then I walked away, came back and when I returned I had some auto-generated emails (new things had loaded - slowly). Did this mean that maybe my module had also become accessible? I checked, and sure enough, there it was.

ZERO DOCUMENTATION about this

Comment: Can't vote this answer up, because it isn't describing a solution but just a first step. If you add a new module to the addons and already have the addons path set properly, you have to restart the server. And yes, you need to activate the developer mode in Odoo 9 (not in 8 and lesser) to see some more options under Apps. There you usually need to "Update Apps List", one of the new options. Now you will find your custom module under Apps, but perhaps you need to deactivate the "Apps" Filter, too. This developer mode change in v9 was ... i just hate it...

Comment: Thanks for the rest of the process - I must have updated the apps, saw that nothing happened, then restarted the server. Not just 'walk away and come back.'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the config file.Then send the last error it has.